# Click button to open url in current window

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am using Angular and tried to create a function to open url in current window. Below code in the controller actually opens new window instead:

```
$scope.openUrl = function(url) {
    $window.open(url);
};
```

..when I use this `ng-click='openUrl("someurl")'`

So how to open in current window? I tried `ng-click='parent.open()'` and it doesn't work.

Comment: try this window.location = newUrl;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$window is a wrapper for the browser's native window object. You can use this low-level method to actually change the location:

```
$window.location.href = url;
```

$location is a bit different. It can only extract from and manipulate the browser URL string. Its purpose isn't to actually navigate.

> What does it not do? It does not cause a full page reload when the
>   browser URL is changed. To reload the page after changing the URL, use
>   the lower-level API, $window.location.href.
>   https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve this by using same old vainilla javascript:

```
$scope.openUrl = function(url) {
    window.location = url;
};
```

Comment: It's worth mentioning that the $window wrapper exists to make the window object mockable for testing. It's good practice to use $window instead of window where you're able.